# Disable Button If Combox Input Deleted

Tags: vb.net, combobox, textchanged

In my project, I have a few textbox inputs, and some combo boxes with maybe 2 indexed items on a form. There's a button I'm disabling on load if no input is supplied to both textbox inputs, and it works great even if I delete out any text. However, I'm having issues with forcing the combo box to behave in the same manner. This work however:

```
Private Sub cboPickShirts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboPickShirts.SelectedIndexChanged

    InputCheck_3 = True

    If cboPickShirts.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
        InputCheck_3 = False

    End If

    If InputCheck_3 = False Then
        btnInputResult.Enabled = False

    ElseIf InputCheck_3 = True Then
        btnInputResult.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

I have `InputCheck_3` set up as a global variable in a `Public Module`. On form load, I'm disabling my button and it doesn't enable until I select one of the indexed items. My struggle to get the button disable again if any combo box text is entered and deleted out, leaving it null or empty. Any thoughts on what I'm missing or what I can add to get results? I guess I need a variable or event to notice the change (entering & deletion of text).

Comment: Can a cboPickShirts.SelectedIndex be less than zero ?

Comment: Yes, as it's being used for testing a condition: If the input in the combo box is less than the number of items in the index for that combo box, do something...

Since zero is the beginning of an index, I'm basically saying if nothing in the index is populated, then perform some action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that your `SelectedIndexChanged` event is not being triggered when you remove the selected item from your ComboBox. I would use the TextChanged event of your TextBox's and ComboBox and give it a common handler and check it that way.  Something like this

```
Private Sub TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, cboPickShirts.TextChanged
    EnableCheck()
End Sub

Private Sub EnableCheck()
    btnInputResult.Enabled = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) And ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1) 
End Sub
```

You can also check that the comboBox is NullorEmpty the same way as the textbox's. As it stands right now the combobox will be enabled when the text no longer matches a selection.

Comment: Most esteemed to have you guys who've been around, this was most excellent. However, I added another combo box, and ran into the issue of the button enabling itself... but I solved that :) Just expanded your suggested check method to account for all the controls being empty, and added on the last combo control to `TextChanged` sub, and all was well. Also, I did have setup a 4th `InputCheck` module for last combo. This was great Mark, and is definitely one to keep on the shelf thought wise.

Answer (score 1):

One line code

```
btnInputResult.Enabled = If((cboPickShirts.SelectedIndex<0),False, True)
```

Comment: @DesignerMind, does it fix your issue?

Comment: No. I can achieve this, however, the goal is to make sure that if any random text is "typed into the combo box" aside from NOT picking an index item (Selected Index), then the comb box stays disabled. Even if you type in text and delete it. While this enables the button, if the value is deleted, the button remains enabled.